Adobe commerce data ingestion to elastic search cloud as third party search
Read this article that says Adobe commerce cloud doesn't support Elasticsearch 7.1+. But I still want to use Elastic search cloud as a third party search tool for Adobe commerce.
Elastic search Paas offering also doesn't have a native Adobe Commerce connector.
Is there a way to index (latest version) Adobe Commerce cloud product data to ElasticSearch cloud?
Does Adobe Commerce cloud offering have a REST API to list and select product data?

In your case, the best solution would be to use OpenSearch.

The OpenSearch service is an open-source fork of Elasticsearch 7.10.2,
following the licensing changes for Elasticsearch.

The following instructions may help you with installation:

Set up OpenSearch service
Migrating to OpenSearch

P.S. ElasticSearch changed license and this became a problem for using it as a service solution in the clouds. A possible solution may be an on-premises installation of Adobe Commerce.
